# Probability on intersection

Tags: probability

If I have two sub-areas confined in a larger area, and I have the intersection of these two sub-areas. If I replace one of the sub-areas with a new sub-area, which is the same size.

What is the probability of the new intersection being bigger than the old one? (By that I mean how could I solve this?)

If the question is too vague or written badly then just comment aand I'll try to explain it a little better.

Thanks
Keri

Comment: Please elaborate!

Comment: Do not include your name and Thanks.

Comment: I have an area of the earth's surface as 64800. On this surface I have two areas. One is 1186 and the other is 1777, and with these I have found their intersection which is 75. Now if I took the area which is 1777 and replaced it with another area of the same size, but in a different place, what's the liklihood that my new intersection will be bigger than the one before?